# Nextflow unzip gz file error: not a regular file

Tags: nextflow, gunzip

I am new to Nextflow and I want to unzip a fastq.gz file. But It raised the error `gunzip: SRR1659960_05pc_R1.fastq.gz is not a regular file`.
I tried to run the same command directly in my console, it works well.
My Nextflow script is:

```
process gz_uncompress{
    input:
        path fastq_r1_gz_path
    output:
        path fastq_r1_path
    script:
    """
    gunzip -kd $fastq_r1_gz_path > "fastq_r1_path.fastq"
    """
}

workflow{
    gz_uncompress("/Users/test/PycharmProjects/nf-easyfuse/local_test/SRR1659960_05pc_R1.fastq.gz")
}
```

The error message is:

```
local_test ywan$ nextflow run t2.nf 
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.10.3
Launching `t2.nf` [peaceful_wilson] DSL2 - revision: bf9e3bc592
executor >  local (1)
[36/f8301b] process > gz_uncompress [  0%] 0 of 1
Error executing process > 'gz_uncompress'

Caused by:
  Process `gz_uncompress` terminated with an error exit status (1)

Command executed:

  gunzip -kd SRR1659960_05pc_R1.fastq.gz > "fastq_r1_path.fastq"

Command exit status:
  1
executor >  local (1)
[36/f8301b] process > gz_uncompress [100%] 1 of 1, failed: 1 ✘
Error executing process > 'gz_uncompress'

Caused by:
  Process `gz_uncompress` terminated with an error exit status (1)

Command executed:

  gunzip -kd SRR1659960_05pc_R1.fastq.gz > "fastq_r1_path.fastq"

Command exit status:
  1

Command output:
  (empty)

Command error:
  gunzip: SRR1659960_05pc_R1.fastq.gz is not a regular file

Work dir:
  /Users/test/PycharmProjects/nf-easyfuse/local_test/work/36/f8301b816e9eb834597ff1e6616c51

Tip: view the complete command output by changing to the process work dir and entering the command `cat .command.out`
```

But when I ran `gunzip -kd SRR1659960_05pc_R1.fastq.gz > "fastq_r1_path.fastq"` in my console, there isn't any errors.

Could you please help me to figure out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Nextflow will try to stage process [input files](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#input-type-file) using symbolic links (this can be changed using the [`StageInMode`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#stageinmode) directive). With `gunzip`, just make sure you write the output to stdout, using `-c`:

> -c --stdout --to-stdout
>
> Write output on standard output; keep original files unchanged.  If there are several input files, the output consists of a
> sequence of independently compressed members. To obtain better
> compression, concatenate all input files before compressing them.

For example:

```
params.fastq = './test.fastq.gz'


process gunzip_fastq {

    input:
    path fastq_gz

    output:
    path fastq_gz.baseName

    script:
    """
    gunzip -c "${fastq_gz}" > "${fastq_gz.baseName}"
    """
}

workflow{

    fastq = file( params.fastq )

    gunzip_fastq( fastq )
}
```

On most systems, you could also just use `zcat` for this. The `zcat` command is identical to `gunzip -c`.

Answer (score -1):

I found add the option `-f` can fix this issue.

```
process gz_uncompress2{
    input:
        path f1
    output:
        path "*.fastq"
    script:
    """
    gunzip -fkd $f1 > fastq_r1_path
    """
}

workflow{
    path = gz_uncompress2("/Users/test/PycharmProjects/nf-easyfuse/local_test/SRR1659960_05pc_R1.fastq.gz")
    path.view()
}
```